# Why angular is assigning a result set with different properties name to an interface with different names? How it is even working?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, observable, webapi

Angular is weird or is it me coming from a backend background finding it weird.

See, I have this interface in angular

```
export interface apiHero
{
    Id: number,
    Nam: string    
}
```

and then I am assigning it something which is returned from the webAPI.

In component,

```
HeroesWebAPI: apiHero[]= [];

getHeroes(): void
   {
      console.log("getHeroes called");
      this.heroService.getHeroesFromWebAPI().subscribe( r => {this.HeroesWebAPI= r; 
        console.log("Final hit:"+  this.HeroesWebAPI)});
      
      
   }
```

service:

```
 getHeroesFromWebAPI(): Observable<any>
  {    
    return this.http.get<any>("https://localhost:44320/api/values").pipe(
      map(res => JSON.stringify(res))
    );
  }
```

Now the weird part, notice the interface? It has `Id` and `Nam` properties, `Nam` not `Name` but the `webAPI` returns an array of a class with properties `Id` and `Name`

```
 public class Hero
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and when I check in console the result of component function, it is

Final hit:`[{"Id":1,"Name":"Johns"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Tonny"}]`

How did It map to an interface with a different property?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't check that properties match at runtime. It doesn't actually "map" the HTTP response to corresponding properties for you automatically. It's not AutoMapper or similar. If the properties don't match, assuming the types are okay at compile time, which they are because `any` can be assigned to anything, then at runtime it will just get whatever came from the API.

Comment: this could be argued with the angular community as a FLAW, right? because it should not happen.

Comment: by the way, what do I do to make it throw an error? returning apiHero instead of any would do the thing?

Comment: To be clear, this is not an angular issue specifically, it's TypeScript. Also some might consider this a positive that it can be more "flexible" and not error/crash. If you need to check the response from the server, there are plenty of well documented and well tested parsing/validation libraries. Also this highlights the need for thoroughly testing the application.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky exactly my point, is it eligible to be reported as an issue on github? I should do so

Comment: It's not up to me, if you want to do that then go for it. Keep in mind, YOU can do a check against the response or against the generated array of objects and throw an error if something is not right.

Comment: thanks, it was a nice point out and your replied with amazing answers, i wil leave it open to get some more insights and later would accept yours or someone's as an answer. thanks